# In which place in the code to connect Qt SIGNALS and SLOTS for best code readability?

Tags: qt, signals-slots

I'm starting to program in Qt and am looking for best practices on where in the code to write the `connect` statements so that the code is more readable.

From the current perspective, it seems that defining `connect` on arbitrary locations (provided that the arbitrary locations don't mean a functional difference) can lead to very hard code to read.

Currently, I find the most intuitive way to define the `connect` statements in the constructor of the class that contains the SLOTS.

Is there a standard or a recommended *best practice*?

Comment: For your main UI, you'd generally have a function that initializes all your widgets, wouldn't you?  Wouldn't that be the best place?

Comment: I am not aware of any recommended way. In my practice I install objects' connections `soon after they are defined`.

Comment: @paulsm4 I don't know. From the current perspective, i would like to define the `connect` as closest as possible to the SLOTS so that I can easily see on what SIGNAL the action is executed. So the answer to the question, yes it would but just for the SLOTS on the gui. I, however, still haven't found for the bad side of this approach.

Comment: i usually contain them into separate functions. like `setupSignalsSlots()` to set the default ones and for dynamically connections i use something like `disconnectSignalsSlotsFor<whatever>()` to ensure all gets disconnected and `setupSignalsSlotsFor<whatever>()` to connect them again the way i need them ... used this a lot when using widgets instead of model/view and using the same widget all over the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to have a function for each "main" part of my layout for initialization. Below is an example of a constructor. Each of the `create` functions returns a group box widget.

```
MissionConfiguration::MissionConfiguration(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent) 
{
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(createMissionConfigurationGroupBox());
    layout->addWidget(createNetAcquireGroupBox());
    layout->addWidget(createSystemStatus());
    layout->addWidget(createStatusButtons());
    setLayout(layout);
}
```

In each of these "create" functions, the appropriate signals/slots are connected. It helps me keep things organized if the widget is complicated.

Here is an example of the `createStatusButtons` function:

```
QGroupBox* MissionConfiguration::createStatusButtons() {
    // on the qbutton status
    QGroupBox *runModes = new QGroupBox(tr("Run Modes"));
    QHBoxLayout *runModeLayout = new QHBoxLayout;

    live = new QRadioButton(tr("Live"));
    playback = new QRadioButton(tr("Playback"));
    simulation = new QRadioButton(tr("Simulation"));
    QPushButton *logout = new QPushButton("Logout");

    simulation->setChecked(true);

    connect(recorder, SIGNAL(isConnected(bool)), live, SLOT(setEnabled(bool)));
    connect(recorder, SIGNAL(isConnected(bool)), playback, SLOT(setEnabled(bool)));
    connect(logout, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(logout()));

    runModeLayout->addWidget(live);
    runModeLayout->addWidget(playback);
    runModeLayout->addWidget(simulation);
    runModeLayout->addWidget(logout);
    runModes->setLayout(runModeLayout);
    return runModes;
}
```

Really, the "best" way to do is is how you like it and what is easy for you to remember. I recommend coming up with an idiom that you can understand, so in the future if you have to edit your code, you'll know exactly where to look.